# Why declare function inside another function makes it globally accessible in php, and how to properly manage it?

Tags: php

This question might have been raised a couple times, but I haven't found a satisfying answer so far, let's see this code:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public static function init()
    {
        function some_function()
        {
            echo "I am globally accessible";
        }
    }
}

SomeClass::init();

// now I can access some_function globally
// this will output: I am globally accessible
some_function();
```

I found out from php documentation in http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php, it says that any function which is declared inside a function will be globally accessible. What I don't understand is why it is designed this way.

I have an idea to utilize this feature, such as to create a helper function that is frequently used, such as in a controller and view of a custom developed mvc framework, therefore I simply call the function `some_function()` rather than call a class/object method `self::some_function()` or `$this->some_function()`, but I couldn't found any info on how to properly use this feature and manage the globally accessible functions declared there.

Comment: Irrespective of why it was designed that way, why do you even feel the need to do this?

Comment: What you're saying isn't quite true anyway: the function will be defined in the appropriate namespace: if you're not using namespacing, then it will be defined in the global namespace

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using closures instead if you want your functions defined within the scope of a class/method

Comment: Please don't use globally accessible variables and functions. This is an extremely bad practice.

Comment: All PHP functions are globally accessible. Confusion comes from the fact that you use the same `function` keyword to define class methods.

Comment: @MarkBaker I am aware of closures and this is not the case. I feel like it's better to put it inside another function, then load and make them globally accessible only when necessary, rather than intentionally writing it in global scope.

Comment: You'll have to ask the designers of the language why they chose to put nested functions in namespace scope; but your preference is to do something that the language wasn't designed to do: nested functions is generally not considered good design anyway, and their use is actively deterred

Answer (score 0):

While it's a known feature of PHP, nested functions aren't commonly used and with good reason.  They produce behaviour that's difficult to cope with.  For example, you can't call some_function() without having called init() first in your example, because some_function() won't be defined until init() is called.  For another, nested functions don't end up within the scope of their container, they end up on the namespace of the container's namespace.

Other than for some sort of putative obfuscated PHP competition, I'd avoid these things like the plague.